# Dotnet pack doesn't respect dynamic variables for version attribute

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, nuget-package

Hey I have been trying to change my csproj to use the .net core style. The project is a class library that I generate a nuget package from. All seems to work fine with the changes if I specify the value as a hard coded value

```
<Version>1.0.1.1</Version>
```

However I am trying to use a shared assembly file to drive the version of a few projects in the sln. Which works fine for the dll but not the nuget package it generates. running `dotnet pack` has the same issue.

I tried a couple things to get this to work but the most surprising seems to be how it ignores variables. e.g.

`InitialTargets="SetVersion"`

```
<Target Name="SetVersion">
<PropertyGroup>
  <Version>1.0.1.1</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

```
<Version>$(Version)</Version>
```

The dlls generated all have version 1.0.1.1 or whatever the variable is set to. However the nuget package still just generates version 1.0.0.0.

The exact same output if I specify:

```
<GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
```

And let it read the version from the SharedAssembly.cs file. The dlls are the correct version but not the nuget package.

I know I could just specify the version when calling `dotnet pack` but was hoping to avoid that and have it just happen correctly when running the build from VS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `<PackageVersion>`: this is the MSBuild property so it have to go within a `<PropertyGroup>` group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.1.1</PackageVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```